# Given a number, getting a grid position in a spiral pattern

Tags: algorithms

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  20       | id:  19       | id:  18       | id:  17       | id:  16       |
| pos: (-2, -2) | pos: (-1, -2) | pos: (0, -2)  | pos: (1, -2)  | pos: (2, -2)  |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  21       | id:  6        | id:  5        | id:  4        | id:  15       |
| pos: (-2, -1) | pos: (-1, -1) | pos: (0, -1)  | pos: (1, -1)  | pos: (2, -1)  |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  22       | id:  7        | id:  0        | id:  3        | id:  14       |
| pos: (-2, 0)  | pos: (-1, 0)  | pos: (0, 0)   | pos: (1, 0)   | pos: (2, 0)   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  23       | id:  8        | id:  1        | id:  2        | id:  13       |
| pos: (-2, 1)  | pos: (-1, 1)  | pos: (0, 1)   | pos: (1, 1)   | pos: (2, 1)   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  24       | id:  9        | id:  10       | id:  11       | id:  12       |
| pos: (-2, 2)  | pos: (-1, 2)  | pos: (0, 2)   | pos: (1, 2)   | pos: (2, 2)   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Given a grid, starting at the center and spiraling out like the above. I'm trying to find an algorithm that given an `id` returns a `pos`. Is there an algorithm that works like this? I don't want to use a lookup table or anything like that as the grid could be any size.

Comment: Ooh, this would make a great code golf

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49461011/

Comment: @Blacksilver - https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/160148

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give a hint by breaking down the problem into nice looking components. I'll leave it to you to implement the components and use them yourself.

1) A function from `id` to the `ring number` it is in.
For example,

- `id` 0 is in the 0th ring.
- `id` 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 is in the 1st ring.

2) A function from `ring number` to the last `id` of the ring.
For example,

- 0th ring's last `id` is 0
- 1st ring's last `id` is 8
- 2nd ring's last `id` is 24

3) A function from `ring number` to the last `pos` of the ring. For example,

- 0th ring's last `pos` is (0,0)
- 1st ring's last `pos` is (-1,1)
- 2nd ring's last `pos` is (-2,2)

4) A function from `id` to the `increment of pos` to reach the next `id`. Let's call this function $g$. For example,

- $g(10) = (1,0)$
- $g(20) = (0,-1)$

It has to do with what part of the ring the `id` is in.

Hopefully, this has structured the problem in a way you can see the solution easier by yourself.

Comment: This helped a lot. I did 4 a little different but it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

My javascript implementation...

```
function getRing (id) {
 return Math.ceil((Math.sqrt(id + 1) - 1) / 2);
}

function getMinRingID (r) {
 if (r == 0) {
   return 0;
 }
 return Math.pow((2 * (r - 1) + 1), 2);
}

function getRingLegFromID (id) {
 if (id == 0) {
   return 0;
 }

 var r = getRing(id);
 var m = getMinRingID(r);
 if (id >= m && id < m + (2 * r)) {
   return 0;
 } else if (id >=  m + (2 * r) && id <  m + (4 * r)) {
   return 1;
 } else if (id >=  m + (4 * r) && id <  m + (6 * r)) {
   return 2;
 } else if (id >=  m + (6 * r)) {
   return 3;
 }
}
```

With the above basics, you can get the position with...

```
function getPos (id) {
 var ring = getRing(id);
 var min = getMinRingID(ring);
 var leg = getRingLegFromID(id);

 if (id === 0) {
   return [0, 0];
 }

 switch (leg) {
   case 0:
     return [-ring + ((id - min) + 1), ring];
     break;
   case 1:
     return [ring, ring - ((id - min) - ((2 * ring) - 1))];
     break;
   case 2:
     return [ring - ((id - min) - ((4 * ring) - 1)), -ring];
     break;
   case 3:
     return [-ring, -ring + ((id - min) - ((6 * ring) - 1))];
     break;
 }
}
```

The test...

```
for (var id = 0; id < 49; id ++) {
 var ring = getRing(id);
 var min = getMinRingID(ring);
 var leg = getRingLegFromID(id);
 var pos = getPos(id);

 console.log('id = ' + id + '; ring = ' + ring + '; leg = ' + leg + '; pos = ' + pos);
}
```